# 23-hour clock app?

Tags: timer

The answer to this question is probably going to be "no", but I'm going to try anyway.

Is there a clock-app, preferably an android app, (or an actual physical watch, though this is not the forum for that), that has a non-standard day-length such as 23 hours? 23 hours would be nice, but even better would be one that has an adjustable duration.

Let me be clear what I mean:

- one hour lasts the same amount of time on this clock as on standard clocks,
- but there are only 23 hours in a single "day" (or preferably, an adjustable amount). That means that one "day" on this clock lasts 23\24ths the time that a normal day lasts, so that after one "day" on this clock, the earth has only made 23/24ths of a rotation. That means that if it now says 14:00 on both a normal clock and this weird clock, then 24 hours later it will say 14:00 on the normal clock, and 15:00 on the weird clock. 48 hours it will say 14:00 and 16:00, etc.

I want this in order to regulate a shorter sleep-cycle.

Is there a way to get this? I obviously already searched the app-store and couldn't find anything since this is obviously not a commonly desired thing.

Comment: It's certainly possible to implement this. Your definition just misses one thing: there's one point in time where the world time and weird time are the same. When should that be, or, do you need it to be configurable?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I would need to have the ability to set the time on the clock, the same way you can do this for normal clocks. e.g. at any given time, I should just be able to set the clock to 14:34 or 05:28

Comment: So in that case, the date would be set to world date = weird date. And the time to world time = whatever you set time. After 24 days the time will match again, but the date is one day off.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, yes that is right, except that I don't really need there to be a weird date at all. I just need a 23 hour clock, not a 23 hour calendar.

Comment: I am not sure how that will help your sleep cycle, but it will get you going to bed an hour earlier every day, until you are going to bed at noon :-)

Comment: @Mawg, If I sleep 8 hours, and stay awake for 15 hours, then on the normal clock am waking up at different times each day, but not on this weird clock.

Comment: But, in the real world, the day is shifting by an hour; even if you don't have work or school, you will soon be trying to fall asleep in the day & will be sleeping at times when your friends are awake (plus you will miss your favo(u)rite TV shows :-)

Comment: @Mawg, I am aware of this of course

Comment: The, good luck to you. I am sure that it will be interesting :-) Even if I still don't understand how it will help your sleep regimen :-/ But, NVM, that's not germane to the question

Comment: Maybe you could start by using a countdown timer that auto resets. Set it to 23 hours and it will run backwards to zero and start again.